# How can I make my path look more like apple or google draws their path on maps?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I made a navigation app to show the shortest distance between two points on a graph with nodes.
I draw a path between every node but the corners does not fit well to each other and it looks like this:

[image]

To **draw** a route I did the following:

```
   if (ms.path != nil) {
            NodeModel *startNode = nil;
            bool isOverview = [self isOverviewMap];

            for (NodeInPath *endNode in ms.path.allNodes) {
                if (startNode != nil) {
                    if (isOverview || ([startNode.mapId isEqualToString:mapsource.map->mapId] && [endNode.mapId isEqualToString:mapsource.map->mapId])) {

                        CAShapeLayer *elemLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    #ifdef HALL_DEBUG
                        if ([startNode.mapId intValue] == 0 && [endNode.mapId intValue] == 0) {
                            elemLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
                        } else if ([startNode.mapId intValue] == 0 || [endNode.mapId intValue] == 0) {
                            elemLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
                        } else {
                            if (startNode.kartenelementId.length != 0 || endNode.kartenelementId.length != 0) {
                                elemLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
                            } else {
                                elemLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
                            }
                        }
    #else
                        elemLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    #endif
                        elemLayer.fillRule    = kCAFillRuleNonZero;
                        elemLayer.position    = CGPointZero;
                        elemLayer.lineWidth   = 30;


                        CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

                        if (isOverview) {
                            CGPathMoveToPoint(path, 0, startNode.overviewX, startNode.overviewY);
                            CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, 0, endNode.overviewX, endNode.overviewY);
                        } else if ([startNode.mapId isEqualToString:mapsource.map->mapId] && [endNode.mapId isEqualToString:mapsource.map->mapId]) {
                            CGPathMoveToPoint(path, 0, startNode.mapX, startNode.mapY);
                            CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, 0, endNode.mapX, endNode.mapY);
                        }
                        CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

                        elemLayer.path        = path;
                        CGPathRelease(path);

                        [markerLayer addSublayer:elemLayer];

                        // p1
                        path = CGPathCreateMutable();
                        CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
                        circleLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
                        circleLayer.fillColor   = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
                        circleLayer.fillRule    = kCAFillRuleNonZero;
                        circleLayer.position    = CGPointZero;
                        circleLayer.lineWidth   = 30;
                        circleLayer.path        = path;
                        CGPathRelease(path);

                        CGRect rect;

                        if (isOverview) {
                            rect = CGRectOffset(CGRectMake(startNode.overviewX, startNode.overviewY, 5, 5), -2, -2);
                        } else {
                            rect = CGRectOffset(CGRectMake(startNode.mapX, startNode.mapY, 5, 5), -2, -2);
                        }
                        CGPathAddEllipseInRect((CGMutablePathRef)circleLayer.path, 0, rect);
                        [markerLayer addSublayer:circleLayer];

                        if (endNode == [ms.path.allNodes objectAtIndex:ms.path.allNodes.count - 1]) {
                            // p2
                            path = CGPathCreateMutable();
                            circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
                            circleLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
                            circleLayer.fillColor   = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
                            circleLayer.fillRule    = kCAFillRuleNonZero;
                            circleLayer.position    = CGPointZero;
                            circleLayer.lineWidth   = 30;
                            circleLayer.path        = path;
                            CGPathRelease(path);

                            if (isOverview) {
                                rect = CGRectOffset(CGRectMake(endNode.overviewX, endNode.overviewY, 5, 5), -2, -2);
                            } else {
                                rect = CGRectOffset(CGRectMake(endNode.mapX, endNode.mapY, 5, 5), -2, -2);
                            }
                            CGPathAddEllipseInRect((CGMutablePathRef)circleLayer.path, 0, rect);
                            [markerLayer addSublayer:circleLayer];
                        }

                        if (endNode.description.length > 0) {
                            if (isOverview) {
                                rect = CGRectOffset(CGRectMake(endNode.overviewX, endNode.overviewY, 5, 5), -2, -2);
                            } else {
                                rect = CGRectOffset(CGRectMake(endNode.mapX, endNode.mapY, 5, 5), -2, -2);
                            }
                            [self addMarkerAtPosition:CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + rect.size.width/2, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height/2) withTitle:endNode.description favorite:false];
                        }
                    }
                }
                startNode = endNode;
            }
        }
```

Any ideas on how to make it look more like apple or google maps does it? Or at least make the corners fit well to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would rounded line caps do it? Try this... also setting the line joins to rounded, as this will make line segments on the same path look better as well.

```
CAShapeLayer *elemLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
elemLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;
elemLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
```